# Installing a second RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have one RoR system setup on my computer for a project, and I'm looking to setup a second one in a different folder.  Is there documentation/steps I can follow so that I do not mess up the original app?

Comment: What are you concerned will happen?

Comment: I'm concerned I might overwrite some files... or add certain gems to one project that I don't need for another

Comment: As long as you leave the directory of your existing app there is nothing to be concerned about...

Comment: Hmm.. I might be confused then as to what I am trying to do.  THanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to create a new Rails app, then running `rails new insert_app_name` should be sufficient. I'd recommend doing that outside of your other app's directory.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be using an rvm(ruby version manager) and rvm gemsets

suppose your one ror project is in folder named FOLDER, come out of the project

```
        `username@FOLDER/projectname $ cd..`
```

check which ruby version by running the below command

```
         `username@FOLDER $ rvm list`
```

use a particular ruby version by

```
         `username@FOLDER $ rvm use ruby-version`
```

then create a rvm gemset to use for particular project

```
         `username@FOLDER $ rvm gemset create gemset-name`
```

then use the gemset

```
         `username@FOLDER $ rvm gemset use gemset-name`
```

now use this gemset to have a different rails version and create a new project

```
         `username@FOLDER $ gem install rails -v version-number`

         `username@FOLDER $ rails new projectname`
```

Hope this explains dividing of ruby version and rails version for different projects

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use different gemset for each rails application so that gems are not conflicting with each other.

Command to create gemset:

```
rvm gemset create gemset_name
rvm gemset use gemset_name
```